# AHK: Middle-mouse should drag-lock

Tags: autohotkey

Recently got new Windows 11 computer, can't get used to the "Tap twice and drag to multi-select" touchpad setting, on my PC it starts selecting just when I'm trying to move mouse right after a click. So I disabled it, and wanting to do something similar I came up this this AHK 2.0 script that will enable drag-lock on middle-mouse click, then I bound three-finger touchpad tap/click (Windows 11 settings) to middle-mouse button. Works pretty well, but need help with finishing touches:

```
toggle := false

~RButton::
{
    global toggle
    toggle := false
}

~LButton::
{
    global toggle
    toggle := false
}

MButton::
{
    global toggle
    toggle := !toggle
    if (toggle)
        Click "Down"
    else
        Click "Up"
}
```

Right now, if I'm drag-locking to e.g. select text, I need to press middle-button again to keep selection. Pressing left-button will cancel the selection (as it's not only lifting "Up" the key, but clicking wherever I am).

I tried to put an if inside the ~RButton to return if the toggle is true, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, by using the *HotIf* for only messing with left-click when the toggle is true:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_HotIf.htm

```
toggle := false

#HotIf toggle
LButton::
{
    Click "Up"
    global toggle
    toggle := false
}
#HotIf

MButton::
{
    global toggle
    toggle := !toggle
    if toggle
        Click "Down"
    else
        Click "Up"
}
```